# Google Sheets - untick checkbox when a row is modified

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am relatively new to the world of google sheets, and looking for a way to highlight when a product label needs to be regenerated due to a change in it's name.

Ideally I would like to accomplish this with a tickbox next to the products details, which will be ticked once the label has been created with the current details.

If there is a change to the product name, I would like the tickbox to become unchecked, and inturn highlighting the entire row, creating a visual prompt to generate a new label, once the new label has been generated, the user will be able to manually recheck the tickbox which would remove the highlighting of the row.

The conditional formatting of the row based on the TRUE / FALSE is not a problem, just stuck on how to modify the checkbox based on a change on the row.

Any help is appreciated!

Worked through post on https://sheetaki.com/highlight-latest-value-change-rows-google-sheets/ but the solution was not ideal and did not accomplish the goal I had in mind.

Comment: Would you prefer an alternative option that utilizes Apps Script?

Answer (score 2):

### Recommendation:

You can use Appscript onEdit function to achieve your goal. The `onEdit(e)` trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet.

To run the code you can go to Extensions > Appscript on your Spreadsheet.

[image: How to open Appscript]

Then paste the code below and save:

```
 function onEdit(e) {
   var range = e.range;
   var source = e.source.getActiveSheet();
   

  if (range.getColumn() === 1){
  
  source.getRange(range.getRow(),1,1,source.getLastColumn()).setBackground('red');
  source.getRange(range.getRow(),2).clearContent();
  }

  if (range.getColumn() === 2 && source.getRange(range.getRow(),2).setValue(true)) {
  
  source.getRange(range.getRow(),1,1,source.getLastColumn()).setBackground('white');
  

}
}
```

### Output:

[image: onEdit()]

### References:

- [Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: Let me know if this answer helps, or if you have any questions with respect to the answer posted above. I have created a sample data based on your description as you there's no data provided on your post, this is to test and show you how the script works.